# Unexpected result, does $\Big\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\Big\rfloor=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\bigg\lfloor\frac{n+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\bigg\rfloor $

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions, infinitary-combinatorics

While trying to prove something else, I arrived at the result that for $n\in\Bbb{Z}^+$
$$\Big\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\Big\rfloor=\Big\lfloor\frac{n+1}{4}\Big\rfloor+\Big\lfloor\frac{n+3}{8}\Big\rfloor+\Big\lfloor\frac{n+7}{16}\Big\rfloor+\cdots=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\bigg\lfloor\frac{n+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\bigg\rfloor$$
This result was quite spectacular to me and I want to know if it is true and if it is how I can prove it. For all cases I've tried it seems to hold true.

Comment: $n/2=n/4+n/8+\cdots$ so it seems reasonable that this could be true! But I never heard of it before.

Answer (score 4):

The following claim: 
$$\tag1\sum_{i=0}^\infty\bigg\lfloor\frac{n+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\bigg\rfloor=1 $$
clearly holds for $n=1$.

We have
$$ \sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n+2^i}{2^{i+1}}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor \frac{n+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\right\rfloor\right)=\sum_{i\ge0\atop 2^{i+1}\mid n+2^i}1=\sum_{i\ge0\atop2^i\|n}1=1$$
because there is exactly one $i\ge0$ such that $2^i\|n$. Hence by induction $(1)$ holds for all $n$.
As one also verifies
$$\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor =n$$
(e.g., by case distinction whether $n=2m$ or $n=2m+1$), your result follows.

Comment: Is there a typo for $(1)$, I have it coming out to $0$ for $n=1$. $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{1+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\rfloor=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\rfloor=0$.

Comment: also I believe it would be $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor =n$.

Comment: @KevinShannon You are correct. Claim ($1$) should be $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\bigg\lfloor\frac{n+2^i-1}{2^{i+1}}\bigg\rfloor=n-1$ for all $n\ge1$. What we then need at the end is $\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor =(n-1)-\left\lfloor\frac{n}2\right\rfloor$, because the right hand side is the result of ($1$) minus the $0$'th term, which gives the series in your question. Personally, I think we might as well sum from $i=1$ from the beginning. Then the difference calculation in the answer would be $1$ whenever $n$ is even, which is what we want. Except that ($1$) is a nice result in itself of course